# Cannot start postgres service

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have postgres on my pc and I work with it every day.

But today when I tried to connect to postgres, I did not manage to do it.

I decide to start it by typing `systemctl start postgresql@10-main`, by I have this output:

> Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because a configured
>   resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status
>   postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

then I type

```
systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
```

like he say, this is the output:

```
postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since ث 2019-10-22 14:09:28 CET; 15s ago
  Process: 9179 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

أكت 22 14:09:28 mobelite-Inspiron-7577 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
أكت 22 14:09:28 mobelite-Inspiron-7577 postgresql@10-main[9179]: Error: Config owner (postgres:121) and data owner (systemd-network:101) do not match, and config owner is not root
أكت 22 14:09:28 mobelite-Inspiron-7577 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: PID file /run/postgresql/10-main.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
أكت 22 14:09:28 mobelite-Inspiron-7577 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
أكت 22 14:09:28 mobelite-Inspiron-7577 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
أكت 22 14:09:28 mobelite-Inspiron-7577 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

The Postgres logs say:

```
2019-10-22 09:33:19.718 CET [4588] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432 
2019-10-22 09:33:19.718 CET [4588] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432 
2019-10-22 09:33:20.062 CET [4588] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" 
2019-10-22 09:33:20.528 CET [4590] LOG: database system was shut down at 
2019-10-20 21:02:17 CET 2019-10-22 09:33:20.937 CET [4588] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections 
2019-10-22 09:33:21.536 CET [4603] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: incomplete startup packet 
2019-10-22 10:06:18.170 CET [10958] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: invalid length of startup packet 
2019-10-22 10:41:37.536 CET [13788] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: invalid length of startup packet 
2019-10-22 11:00:13.521 CET [4588] LOG: received fast shutdown request 
2019-10-22 11:00:13.561 CET [4588] LOG: aborting any active transactions 
2019-10-22 11:00:13.565 CET [4588] LOG: worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 4599) exited with exit code 1 
2019-10-22 11:00:13.566 CET [4594] LOG: shutting down 
2019-10-22 11:00:13.699 CET [4588] LOG: database system is shut down
```

Can anyone help me please

Comment: What did you try so far to address the `Error:` from the log?

Comment: Try `df -h` and see if your partition is out of space.